# Visual Studio incorrectly smart indents the opening brace

Tags: visual-studio, formatting, editor

When I type the closing brace in an html page, this i what Visual Studio does. Notice the opening brace is now 1 indent before the foreach. They should be even as shown by the closing brace. Not a big thing but driving me nuts.

```
<% foreach (var item in Model.Messages)
{ %>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In code view press Ctrl+E,D It will auto-format/indent your code.

Comment: Try Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D ;) http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/files/Visual%20Studio%20.NET%202005%20Keyboard%20Shortcuts.htm

Comment: Visual Studio 2008 / 2010 the shortcut is Ctrl+E,D. Mouse over Edit->Advanced->Format Document

Comment: In the default settings for 2008 Ctrl+E, D and Ctrl+E, Ctrl+D and Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D run the same command. Learned something new about VS. The ED combination makes more sense then KD. I dig the Ctrl+E, Ctrl+D.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> [Pick your language] -> Formatting. You should find something in there.

Answer (score 0):

When I try  Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D in Visual Studio 2010 Express, it says this key combination is bound to the command (Format document) which is not currently available.